# can i use page items in cursor base pagination?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

can i use page items in cursor base pagination? for example  it's possible to directly address a specific page. For instance, if the requirement is to jump directly to page five, it's possible to do so since the pages themselves are not explicitly numbered.

Comment: Please provide more in depth details as well as the relevant code. It's not clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to jump to a specific page with cursor-based pagination.

But it is possible with [offset-based pagination](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/offset-based).